# What to do with ajax forms multiple requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-ajax, ajaxform

Let's say I have two links in my navigation which use `Ajax.BeginForm` with unobtrusive javascript in mvc4. First one makes one request to the database and the second one makes two requests thus taking twice as long. Let's say each request takes one second. Now the user clicks the second link and immediately after - the first link. A scheme of what happens in this order:

1. user clicks link 2
2. user clicks link 1
3. page is loaded for link 1
4. page is loaded for link 2

Let's say the user did this because he realized his mistake immediately after clicking. Now instead of the page 1 expected, he sees it for a split second and then again, he sees a page #2 even tho he didn't want to get to it completely.

First of all, is this a problem? If yes, are there examples on how it should be solved in the most appropriate way? Or maybe I am just chasing wind in the fields and should just forget it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should always abort previous AJAX call, when you are making a new one. It will help your server and give user a desired result.

```
var xhr;

function makeRequest() {
    if (xhr) 
        xhr.abort();

    xhr = $.ajax(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look at disabling the links while the request it ongoing. Maybe just add a simple overlay on your page with a spinner to prevent the user from clicking the other link until the request is completed.

Comment: Is this an idea that comes to your mind from some example you saw in past or just a general suggestion?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius - I have seen this done on sites - the idea being that you want the user to know that there is some process running. Especially if you want to prevent the used from clicking on the button over and over again spooling up new requests.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#loading{
position: absolute;
z-index: 99998;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 1161px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
opacity: 0.01;
background-position: initial initial;
background-repeat: initial initial;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="loading"></div>
```

**Script**

```
 $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
      $( "#loading" ).show();
    });

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
   $( "#loading" ).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this your own creativity or is it an example from a website (or even, several) that treat such things like this? A reference or two could prove to be very valuable.

Comment: all the methods are there in [http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/).And this is my way of usage